# MySQL CASE IGNORE command if condition is false

Tags: mysql, sql, json, null, case

I'm trying to extract a JSON from a table, my code is something like this:

```
SELECT 
JSON_ARRAY(
JSON_OBJECT(
'id', studant.id,
'student', student.name,
'best_grades',
JSON_ARRAYAGG(
CASE
    WHEN class.test_grade = A
    THEN
    JSON_OBJECT(
    'id', class.id,
    'class', class.name,
    'test_grade', class.test_grade
    )
    END
)))
```

It works pretty well, it adds a new object every time the condition is true, but the problem is, when test_grade is different than A it still adding an object, but with null as value, it gets like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "student": "Adam",
    "best_grades": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "class": "Math",
            "test_grade": "A"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "class": "Biology",
            "test_grade": "A"
        },
        null,
        null
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "student": "Susy",
    "best_grades": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "class": "Math",
            "test_grade": "A"
        },
        null,
        {
            "id": 3,
            "class": "History",
            "test_grade": "A"
        },
        null
    ]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "student": "Max",
    "best_grades": [
        null,
        {
            "id": 2,
            "class": "Biology",
            "test_grade": "A"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "class": "History",
            "test_grade": "A"
        },
        null
    ]
}
]
```

What I need is, in case the condition is not true the program just skip to the next object instead of returning null and creating a new object like that.
Basically I want it to IGNORE, SKIP, PASS or DO NOTHING when the grade is different than A, someone told me to do something like

```
CASE
    WHEN class.test_grade = A
    THEN
    JSON_OBJECT(
    'id', class.id,
    'class', class.name,
    'test_grade', class.test_grade
    )
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    END
    END CASE
```

But it doesn't work and says that "'END' is not valid in this position";
Is there a way to make MYSQL ignore the command if the condition is false?

Comment: you need to exclude those class rows in your where condition; you can't do it in the json_arrayagg

Comment: Move JSON_ARRAYAGG into CASE.

Comment: Can't move JSON_ARRAYAGG into CASE, the plan is to create a new JASON_OBJECT, not an array